# Bind NoUiSlider with a span

Tags: javascript, jquery, nouislider

I use NoUiSliders and I want to bind it with a span object. On documentation they have this way:

```
$('#slider1').Link('lower').to($('#slider1value'));
```

However, what I want to do is to not show the value, but use it on a dictionary with the slider's values as keys and take the text from there. For example:

```
var names = ["0":"zero", "1":"one",...]
```

I don't know if it is something that you can do with wNumb from noUiSliders and I tried it by myself with this way:

```
$( "#slider1" )
  .on("slide set change", function() {
    var value = $( this ).val();
    $( "#slider1value" ).text( names[value] );
  })
```

It works as it is now when slider changes, but when the page loads with the predefined values, the span doesn't take the value from slider.

Is there any way to add another event like `initialize` or `load`? Or is there any other way to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the second argument in `.Link()` to do this:

```js
var slider = $('#slider'), target = $('#target');

var names = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'];

slider.noUiSlider({
    range: { min: 0, max: 4 },
    start: 1,
    format: wNumb({ decimals: 0 })
});

slider.Link().to(target, function ( value ) {
    $(this).html(names[value]);
});
```

Note that **wNumb** is used to remove the slider decimals, so the slider value matches the array keys (`0, 1, 2, 3`).

See it in action [here](http://jsfiddle.net/leongersen/qmoL9o0c/).